# Eclipse .project missing

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a folder which contains some previous projects. In the same folder I saved a new project, which messed everything up. So I created a new folder to put my projects in.

[image: workspace]

I found that the problem is that I moved folder locations that I needed to delete .location, which took an hour to find.

After all of this the problem is I can't find the project under

> import > existing projects in workspace

Here is The error that sows up when I try to open minecraft folder

[image: error]

I have .project where it needs to be I just need to solve .location.
Edit:A aswer show up and solved the problem but now this is what pops up
[image: 1ºimage]
[image: 2ºimage]

Comment: Eclipse doesn't seem to think the `.project` file is in the correct place

Comment: ... I know thats because i deleted .location file but know i need to fix that but i dont know how Everione says to reimport But IT needs to be a prokect to import

Comment: You can copy & edit `.project` and `.location` by-hand. (Though, I don't remember Eclipse having `.location` files). If all else fails, you have the project on disk, so remove it from the Eclipse workspace, and File>Import again.

Comment: thats the problem i cant import it doesnt show up i have this image because i still didnt delete the mess... but in my organized one i dont have even minecraft on hierarchy

Comment: Cricket_007 i was looking trought the forums and to change .location you must need hexodecimal ... And I dont have .location so i cant edit it also i checked and theres rummors if i edit the .location it can delete the hole project... Im not taking that risk

Comment: Make a ZIP archive of your code for safe keeping. I do not think you need a Hex Editor. Just a regular text editor will do. But you do need to show hidden files in the Windows Explorer to see said file.

Answer (score 4):

Simply delete your Minecraft project from eclipse workspace and create a new project with the existing directory as a base directory for this project. Below screenshots will show you the step by step process.

Step 1: Working project

[image]

Step 2: Getting error when closed the project and trying to reopen the project in the absence of .project file.

[image]

Step 3: Delete the project from repository (Do not delete the project from disk space)

[image]

[image]

Step 5: Create a new java project

[image]

[image]

Step 6: Provide the project name as "Minecraft" and provide the location of your source directory. Click on finish

[image]

You should see the project imported successfully.

Comment: SO you help me in some sort of way the problem is that now i dont know why i cant find the project mannualy (searching folders) But i have to thank you because ive found the place of class now this is the problem

the packages are folders and the classs i cant access to them it says:
Source not found

Comment: I suppose, you have used "Location" on Step 6 as "..../Minecraft/src/main/java". Instead use "Location" as "..../Minecraft"

Answer (score -1):

At the time of download you might have unzipped an Eclipse then you might have use it now delete the Eclipse but not workspace where you had a project now go to zipped Eclipse which you have downloaded then start Eclipse select previous workspace then it's good to go or else change workspace as well

Comment: When i downloaded it was runnable... and i could access to it